# Dealing with a (partial) integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

I am  dealing with this (partial) integro-differential equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(t,x) &= c_{3}v(t,x) + \int_{x}^{1} K(x,\xi) v(t,\xi)d\xi,\\
v(0,x)&= v_{0}(x)
\end{align}

where $t\in[0,\infty)$, $x\in[0,1]$, $K(x,\xi)$ is a bounded kernel, $c_{3}< 0$, and $v_{0}$ is a given initial condition.

I know that for $x=1$ the solution converges to zero because in this case the equation is reduced to
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(t,1) &= c_{3}v(t,1),\\
v(0,1)&= v_{0}(1).
\end{align}

However, I want to see if the solution is unstable for $x<1$.

Can anyone help me? Any kind of reference would be grateful.

Thanks.